# Arrange DIVs in another DIV

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="upmenu">
    <div class="info" id="info-uberuns"><div>ubernus</div></div>
    <div class="info" id="info-consultant"><div>consultant</div></div>
</div>
```

And this is CSS class:

```
.info{
    position: absolute;
    width: 130px;
    height: 47px;
    z-index: 0;  
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    top: 13px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    padding-top: 5px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}    
.info div{
    margin-left: 20px;
}    
#upmenu{
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

I want to arrange DIVs with info class in the DIV with upmenu class and show them side by side.
But the problem is that they are shown on top of each other instead of being shown side by side.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Regads

Comment: You stuck both divs in the same place with absolute positioning. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.info` class.

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Also remove `position: absolute;` from `.info`

http://jsfiddle.net/G3N24/

Comment: Did you take a look at the fiddle? Removing `position: absolute` and adding `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` does work

Answer (score 1):

You can add float:left to the .info class.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can make the `div`'s display property as `inline-block` like mituw16 showed,

OR

You can make the element itself a `span`, and no need to change any style.

```
<div id="upmenu">
  <span class="info" id="info-uberuns">ubernus</span>
  <span class="info" id="info-consultant">consultant</span>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nagendra_rao/Q52DK/)

Answer (score 1):

A different approach...not any better than other suggestions.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LQzTp/1/)

You can play with the CSS and make it look anyway you want.

HTML

```
<div id="upmenu">
  <div class="info" style="float: left;" id="info-uberuns">
    ubernus
  </div>
  <div class="info" style="float: right;" id="info-consultant">
    consultant
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#upmenu{
    border: 0px solid black;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:40%;
}
.info{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```